# Find an Element with Selenium without ID or Name. Just an data-bind value C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

community,

I have another problem with selenium.
And I would like to thank everyone for their help with my last problem. I can already do a lot myself.

Currently I can't get any further I would like to slide on an element to open the menu below. 
I can and will adjust the hover command and more, but I don't manage to grab the "empty element". Unfortunately, I have to say that no element hides a correct ID.

But can the element be grasped and further processed with the given info? I have searched for days now but nothing has helped.

```
<li class="">
  <a data-bind="attr: { href: link, class: showSeparator() ? 'menuItemSeparator' : ' '}" href="#" class=" ">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw  fa-user" data-bind="class: iconClass"></i> 
    <span class="menu-item-parent" data-bind="attr: {'data-i18n': name}" data-i18n="app:modules.localization.administration.navigation.candidates.root">Text</span>
    <b class="collapse-sign">
      <em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></em>
    </b>
  </a>
  <!-- ko if: children().length > 0 -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

EDIT:
Sorry
I would like to control the element

```
data-i18n
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to locate? the one with `<a>` tag?

Comment: There are 3 elements with `data-bind`, which one do you want to locate?

Comment: You can use xpath axes to locate elements with relation to any other static element. [xpath axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) To help you out more can you share full html of the page?

Comment: @FrankButNotTheTank What exactly do you mean by _control the element_? Do you want to extract the value of the attribute `data-i18n` i.e. **app:modules.localization.administration.navigation.candidates.root**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class name `menu-item-parent`, it seems unique enough

```
driver.findElement(By.className("menu-item-parent"));
```

If you want to locate by the `data-i18n` attribute you can use css selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-i18n]"));
```